# Верна ли архитектура взаимодействия для проекта?

Tags: java, android, windows, веб-сервер, клиент-сервер

Появился проект, подскажите в правильном ли русле я думаю?

Проект: в общем в двух комнатах стоят два коннектора-считывателя, и какому-то предмету прикрепляется метка, и эти коннекторы при считывании, сообщают где находится предмет, коннекторы объедены в сеть с Microsoft Server, на нем развернута база данных, куда поступают данные, также нужно создать Android приложении, в котором оперативно можно посмотреть, где находится предмет, как я вижу общую архитектуру

Коннекторы - Сервер(Microsoft Server) - База Данных - на сервере развернут web server(например на azure) - которые будет взаимодействовать с Android, так ли примерно будет, или совершенно неправильно?

Comment: Правильная или совершенно неправильная архитектура - это вопрос, на который нужно отвечать, имея на руках требования, а их ни в вопросе нет, ни у вас нет. По такой схеме можно построить работающее приложение, вас это интересует? Если это, то ответ тривиальный: да, работать будет.

Comment: да, только это слово хотелось услышать, я думал вообще не в ту сторону копаю) я знаю, что информации то и нет, описал плохо, но спасибо за терпение)